# How can I create another button, which resets the clicks I have done on the JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I´ve done a little clicking game and I wonder how can I create a new Button to reset the clicks I´ve already done.
It should be on the right side of my JLabel.

bubgudbhfbuhdufighbduifhbgudizfhbgudfbhgudhzbfguzdhgbfguzhbfuzsghbuozfsgbusbdfuosdhfuhsdufgh

```
public class Main implements ActionListener {

    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Drücke mich");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100));

        label = new JLabel("Anzahl der Clicks: 0");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Click Spiel");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);




    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Anzahl der Clicks: " + count);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly as you did with the first button add a second button and put a listener on it which will reset the counter.

The aspect related to button placement on the view is another question so it will be up to you to find a solution.

Hint: consider grouping graphic components

```
...
label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

//to be added (solve only reset and not desired display)
//now display bellow Label
JButton reset_button = new JButton("reset");            
reset_button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100));
ActionListener ae = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count = 0;
        label.setText("Anzahl der Clicks: " + count);
    }
};
reset_button.addActionListener(ae);

...
```

Note: Even the default `ActionListener`(increment) can be used but need to filter based on trigger event (which button was clicked and act accordingly)